# While Loop with read in bash script

Tags: bash, while-loop, sh

I have a bash script

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
echo "Debugging: $1"
IFS=' '
frst=true
EXECPATH=$(file $1 | sed -r "s/^.*execfn: '([^']*)'.*$/\1/")
while read x id path x exec
do
    if [ $frst = true ];then
        frst=false
        path=$exec
    fi
.
.
```

Can someone explain what `while read x id path x exec` is? I know `read` reads the output and assign it to variables but why do I have two `x`?

Script is being called like `./myScrpt.sh 'ls filename'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `x` is never used; it's just a dummy variable to capture fields you don't care about, so that the field splitting performed by `read` assigns the desired values to `id`, `path`, and `exec`.

`_` is more commonly used as such a dummy. Also, it's better to simply override the value of `IFS` just for the `read` command than to override it globally and (attempt to) restore its value later.

```
echo "Debugging: $1"
frst=true
EXECPATH=$(file "$1" | sed -r "s/^.*execfn: '([^']*)'.*$/\1/")
while IFS=' ' read _ id path _ exec
do
    if [ "$frst" = true ];then
        frst=false
        path=$exec
    fi
.
.
```

Comment: Whatever the input to `while` is; the rest of the loop probably looks something like `while read ...; do ...; done <<< "$EXECPATH"` (I'm assuming that the output of the pipeline is what is being parsed.)

Comment: first time when control comes to `while` what would it read? For ex. here(https://askubuntu.com/questions/604626/using-while-read-in-a-linux-script) it is reading from `echo` and how many time `while` loop with `read` will run? infinite times?

Comment: It reads *once*; `echo` produces a single line of output, which the first call to `read` consumes entirely.

Comment: It looks like you want `$1` to expand to multiple words (generally a bad idea; use `"$@"` instead of `$1`, and change the call to `./myScrpt.sh ls filename`). In that case, `file` will produce multiple lines of output, and so the `while` loop will process each line one at a time.

Comment: what would be the value of `id` `path` and `exec`?

Comment: That depends on the output of `file`.

Comment: `$1` is ` ls temp.1`
Also can you help finding what does that `sed` command is doing?